# File validation with header signature in PHP

Tags: validation, file-upload, php-5.3

Suppose i have one file a.png. In php we will validate it with extension & mime type.

In form i have make above validation so only png files are going to upload. If i make xyz.pdf to a.png it's going to valid.

I would like to validate file with header signature as in .NET.

Also while upload if image is broken then also it gives the message image is corrupted unable to upload.

In PHP we have to use exif_imagetype ? It's only for image what about files like video, audio or any file ?

Comment: Hey,Did you found any solution?If found please share,I am also facing same issue.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For png images in php, you can also use [createimagefrompng](http://php.net/manual/function.imagecreatefrompng.php)  it returns FALSE if it is not a valid png image file.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the mime type of it. PHP mime_content_type will work on this  but it is already deprecated in PHP 5.3. You can use file_info_file into it.

Take a look at this link for a more detailed explaination:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php
http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php